# Not able to duplicate screen on projector

Tags: hdmi, 23.04, projector

I updated my Ubuntu version to 23.04:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu 
Description:    Ubuntu 23.04
Release:    23.04
Codename:   lunar
```

I want to project my screen using an HDMI port of projector, but when I connect the port I cannot see a second screen:

```
$xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77
```

Driver version:

[image: Driver version]

Settings without an option for another screen:

[image: Settings without an option for another screen]

Can anyone help me in projecting my laptop using HDMI cable?